# Does a non-constant function $f : \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(\bar z)$ is analytic exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

As indicated in the title I am looking for such a function. Or otherwise a brief explanation as to why it does not exist. I have seen some similar questions but none quite the same.

It was out of a true/false set and based on the other answers I'm inclined to believe an example exists, but cannot find one.

Help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: A trivial answer would be that $f$ is the conjugate function.  Do you want a restriction on $f$?  E.g. that it is analytic.

Comment: The only given restriction on f is that f be non-constant.

Comment: If $f$ is supposed to be holomorphic, then the answer is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the function $f(z)=\overline z$.

Comment: Or really let $g$ be any (nonconstant) analytic function and let $f(z) = g(\bar{z})$. You get all possible examples like that...